# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'xL' before initialization

Tags: angular

The app is in Angular 7
Everything works fine in dev mode
But in the prod, i have this error (When i change the order of modules import the error
changes, for example : instead of 'xL' i have 'cw'):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'xL' before initialization
    at Module.<anonymous> (main.ad6bee93d54a1363d352.bundle.js:1:7083960)
    at u (main.ad6bee93d54a1363d352.bundle.js:1:318)
    at main.ad6bee93d54a1363d352.bundle.js:1:1985
    at main.ad6bee93d54a1363d352.bundle.js:1:1996
(anonymous) @ main.ad6bee93d54a1363d352.bundle.js:1
u @ main.ad6bee93d54a1363d352.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.ad6bee93d54a1363d352.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.ad6bee93d54a1363d352.bundle.js:1
```

after setting the optimization.minimize to false like proposed by TmTron in the comment i have this :

> main.6db3b99c9dace04daae7.bundle.js:283567 Uncaught ReferenceError:
> Cannot access
> 'plan_element_rapports_chng_update_component_PlanElementChngRapportsUpdateComponent'
> before initialization

[image]

I think maybe it's a problem in the order of imports (but how to find the right order because it's a big project ?)
any ideas of how to solve this ?

Comment: when the import order matters, I guess you have a circular dependency

Comment: @TmTron   but why the error only occurs in the prod? And if it really is a circular dependency, is there a way to find its location ?

Comment: I don't think it's circular dependency because i used [Madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge)  and i got : ✔ No circular dependency found!

Comment: AFAIK dev and prod build where totally different in Angular 7, so it is well possible that one works, while the other one fails.

Comment: to find out why this occurs can be tricky. you may look at the code in your bundle.js file and maybe get an idea where this comes from. You may also try to tell the angular compiler to not obfuscate/minimize the production build code and see if the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found the problem and solved it, there were import problems in some modules.
For example :
Instead of :

```
import { xxxService } from './xxx.service';
```

we had this:

```
import { xxxService } from './';
```